# How would I insert data into an embeded collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I read through the mongoose and mongo documentation and I still have trouble inserting data into an embedded collection. Here are the two Schema I have

```
  const  itemSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
      name:String
    });

const Item =mongoose.model("Item",itemSchema);

    const  listSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
      name:String,
      items:[itemSchema]
    });

const List=mongoose.model("List",listSchema);
```

I made a new item

```
 const item =new Item({
  name: "apple"
});
```

and I have a new list

```
const list =new List({
name: "fruits",
items:[]
    });
```

so now I would like to insert another List item that has a name fruit, but I don't know what parameter I need to use `List.insertOne()` to target into the items field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asking how to add an item to an existing document right?

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#adding-subdocs-to-arrays

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

```
const myFruitList = await new List({
  name: "fruits",
  items: [{name: "apple"}]
}).save();

// Add another fruit
myFruitList.items.push({name: "bannana"});
await myFruitList.save();
```

Or using update

```
await List.updateOne(
  {name: "fruits"},
  {$push: {items: {name: "bananna"}}}
)
```

Comment: I am sorry for asking this, but can you briefly explain to me how the await works at the beginning?

Comment: No worries, it's an easier way of resolving promises without a callback introduced in ES7. You more than likely are able to use it with your current environment, simply make sure the function containing your queries has ```async``` before it. Read more here https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Instead of ```myFruitList.save().then(saveResult => {...})``` await allows you to write this as ```saveResult = await myFruitList.save()``` This make organization much easier when you have to execute promises one after another